# Importing scanner online IDE

Tags: java

I am trying to use a basic scanner using https://www.compilejava.net/. Here is the code:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HelloWorld
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
       System.out.println("Gimmie a value");
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       int v1 = scan.nextInt();
       System.out.println(v1);
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Gimmie a value
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:29)
```

Comment: What is the Input?

Comment: If you want your program to read an int, you should write an int before pressing "intro"

Answer (score 3):

I did try your code in Eclipse and is working, it looks like the crappy online ide is not supporting the Inputstream, that is why you get an exception...

try using a real IDE instead, or another online ide...

Comment: I don't think you need to call the online tool a crappy IDE.
I'm sure it has its uses to people, it just doesn't support I/O.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your code, but with the online tool. It does not simulate user input. I suggest using one of free desktop programming tools if you are into real programming, like [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org) or [Intellij Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

For the time being, you may try another online tool, like [Ideone](http://ideone.com/). [Here](http://ideone.com/mnsCxp) is a link to your code pasted and adapted to Ideone (note that I had to drop the `public` modifier from the class). Click the "clone" link on the site if you want to work on the code.